# How to decompose C++ namespace to multiple files

Tags: c++, design-patterns, namespaces

I have a big namespace with many functions and variables. 
Now I want to separate them into different files for easy maintenance.

There is only one problem is that one file may need the function/variable from the other files and vice versa i.e. A need to include B and B need to include A.. It does not work since each file can only be include once.

I am not sure if that's the way to do, any idea ?

Comment: Use [forward declaration pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

Answer (score 1):

Put your function *prototypes* into header files (`.h`). Put your function *implemenations* into source files (`.cpp`).

This way you will be able to use, for example functions implemented in `B.cpp` in `A.cpp` by including `B.h` in `A.cpp` at the same time use functions implemented in `A.cpp` in `B.cpp` by including `A.h` in `B.cpp`.

**UPDATE**

As Andrey pointed in comment this is called "Forward declaration".

Comment: thanks, but mine are all template function and class, so i'd rather just keep them in the header files. The forward declaration only works for struct/class, for variable it will throws "redefinition"

Comment: In this case I would recommend you to put your commonly used template functions into shared header (like `Common.h`) and, in turn, include it into both `A.h` and `B.h`. You won't be able to make circular references between template functions anyway due to how templates work in C++.

Comment: You can also forward templates. I usually move template implementations in *.tcc file so the header contains only declarations.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a challenging problem, depending on your code.
You'd need to analyze all dependencies and see if you can come up with an intuitive way to split your code.

The forward declaration already mentioned can help.
It can also help to use interfaces. A lot can be found on Interfaces, [for instance here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)